# Change and persist on yaml a change on an attribute annotated with @Value

Tags: java, spring, yaml

Supposed that I have an attribute of an class annotated with @Value

```
@RestController
public class MyController{
    @Value("${my.host}")
    protected String myHost;
...
```

And I have this attribute mapped on my spring configuration yml file:

```
...
my.host: 10.0.103.144
my.port: 3003
...
```

Is there a way to change the value contained in the attribute myHost and automatically reflect it on my configuraton yml file for this change be persistent?

For example, invoke this with "anotherHost":

```
private changeHost(String newHost) {
    myHost = newHost;
}
```

Would result into this on configuration file:

```
...
my.host: anotherHost
my.port: 3003
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any Spring mechanism to update configuration files automatically.

However, you could use Jackson with a [module that supports YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/yaml) to update your YAML configuration file. It will be something like:

```java
// Create an ObjectMapper mapper for YAML
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

// Parse the YAML file
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(new File("/path/to/file.yml"));

// Update the value
root.put("my.host", "anotherHost");

// Write changes to the YAML file
mapper.writer().writeValue(new File("/path/to/file.yml"), root);
```