# Spring Boot - Update application.yaml at runtime without using external YAML library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way in Spring Boot to update the application.yaml file at runtime without using external YAML library?

Found few threads related to this. [Change and persist on yaml a change on an attribute annotated with @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637098/change-and-persist-on-yaml-a-change-on-an-attribute-annotated-with-value)
 / [spring boot application.yml properties change at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769462/spring-boot-application-yml-properties-change-at-runtime); but this involves using the YAML libray or Spring cloud config.

Comment: I can't really imagine the situation in which you would want to have a stable initial configuration and then change and persist it on runtime, but I'd advise to store the "dynamic" configuration in a separate object and update that, so you keep the initial YAML. In other words initialize your configuration from YAML to some `@Configuration YourConfig.class` and then use that.

Comment: What's wrong with using a YAML library that's already in your classpath?

Comment: @Andreas - Will probably end up using the YAML library if there is no other Spring Boot way of changing it.

Comment: @Dropout - Thanks. Will try this out.

Comment: We have a use case where we're discussing this same topic: key rotation.  Currently some keys are injected to the app yaml before app startup.  They could be updated in the yaml on the fly during key rotations, but the app would need to be restarted to see the changed values.  Seems like a waste to have to have to write our own code to watch for updates to the yaml file and then to update the DB connection with the new password or whatever.